# React. How to deal with missing keys in API response using fetch and setState only for existing keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I am working on a React project that use public API to fetch some data. Problem is I found a lot of interesting and definitely highly valuable API can have some data missing. For example, I am using waqi.info which collect information about air quality from stations all around the world. And here is a problem - when I send requests I need values from a specific key in response JSON. Some stations don't collect part of data, so there is no key I am looking for in JSON. As effect I get what I expect:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'v' of undefined
```

I need to change state only in case key exist in response, or better - set state to the given value like for example 'No data'. 
I can manually check every key for 'undefined' but it is very crude and I am looking for something more smart and elegant. 
Component code (stripped from most unnecessary things) is here:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            dataSourceName: null,
            dataSourceDetailsCO: null,
            dataSourceDetailsNO2: null,
            dataSourceDetailsPM10: null,
            dataSourceDetailsPM25: null,
            dataSourceDetailsSO2: null, 
            dataSourceDetailsTemp: null,
            dataSourceDetailsWind: null
        }; 
    }
    fetchStationDetails = () => {
        const stationUid = this.props.uid;
        const urlStationDetails = 'https://api.waqi.info/feed/@' + stationUid + '/?token=' + apiKey;
        fetch(urlStationDetails)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => this.setState({
                dataSourceName: json.data.attributions[0].name,
                dataSourceDetailsCO: json.data.iaqi.co.v,
                dataSourceDetailsNO2: json.data.iaqi.no2.v,
                dataSourceDetailsPM10: json.data.iaqi.pm10.v,
                dataSourceDetailsPM25: json.data.iaqi.pm25.v,
                dataSourceDetailsSO2: json.data.iaqi.so2.v, 
                dataSourceDetailsTemp: json.data.iaqi.t.v,
                dataSourceDetailsWind: json.data.iaqi.w.v
            })) 
    }
    render(){
        const dataSourceName = this.state.dataSourceName;
        return (
            <li>
                <div>
                    Id: {this.props.uid} Longitude: {this.props.lon} Latitude: {this.props.lat}
                </div>
                <div>
                    General Air Quality Index (AQI): {this.props.aqi}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.fetchStationDetails}>Click to get detailed data</button>
                </div>
                {dataSourceName ? <ItemData 
                    dataSourceName={this.state.dataSourceName}
                    dataSourceDetailsCO={this.state.dataSourceDetailsCO}
                    dataSourceDetailsNO2={this.state.dataSourceDetailsNO2}
                    dataSourceDetailsPM10={this.state.dataSourceDetailsPM10}
                    dataSourceDetailsPM25={this.state.dataSourceDetailsPM25}
                    dataSourceDetailsSO2={this.state.dataSourceDetailsSO2}
                    dataSourceDetailsTemp={this.state.dataSourceDetailsTemp}
                    dataSourceDetailsWind={this.state.dataSourceDetailsWind}
                /> : null }
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: before setting the state just console.log(json) and see if it has all the data that you are getting of of it

Comment: @DhavalChheda I checked response already as you proposed, just stripped all unnecessary code. I get proper response, problem is how to deal with responses that don't have all keys I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, you need always to take this into consideration, what you should try to do is parsing the JSON and checking if the nodes you are looking for are defined or create a whitelist, also there is a lot of duplication in your code you can clean and make it more clear :

```
whiteList = {
    dataSourceName:"co",
    dataSourceDetailsNO2:"no2",
    dataSourceDetailsPM10:"pm10",
    ...
    ...
}

parseData = (data) => {
    try{
        Object.entries(this.whiteList).forEach(([key, value]) => {

            this.setState({
               [key]:data.data.iaqi[value].v
            })
        })
    }catch(e){
        //handle Errors
    }
}


fetchStationDetails = () => {
    const {uid} = this.props;

    const urlStationDetails = `https://api.waqi.info/feed/@${uid}/?token=${apiKey}`;

    fetch(urlStationDetails)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => this.parseData(json)) 
        .catch(console.log)
}
```